# ksoap2 not working on android SDK higher than 8

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 to call multiple web services and here is my code

```
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.dotNet = true;

     try {
           HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);     
        Log.e("beforeCall","before");
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.e("afterCall","before");
           if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
          String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;

               Element detailElem = (Element) details.getElement(0) 
                            .getChild(0); 
               Element e = (Element) detailElem.getChild(2);faultstring; 
           } else {
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

               if(result != null)
               {
                   return result.getProperty(0).toString();
               }
               else
               {
                   Log.d("noResponse", "No Response");   
               }
           }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Exception","exception");
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return null;

}
```

and i am getting the response from another class like this:

```
String Response = ApiCalls.NewProfile("Param1","Param1","Param1");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and it works just fine on sdk version 8, but i am using `min=11` and `target = 17`
the log **"BeforCall"** is seen and appears in the **LogCat** but the "**AfterCall**" dont and the response is `null`.
is there any equivalent call statement for my sdk version ?